# python environment in WSL1 Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu on WSL1 then installed python3 & pip3.

However, anything installed through pip returns an error message `module not found`. Using `whereis`, such as in `whereis pandas` returns `pandas:` with nothing following it, which I speculate to mean it exists to some extent. Attempting to install it again, regardless of what I am installing through pip, returns `name is already at latest version x.x.xx`.

I imagine this might mean that pip is installing to the wrong location perhaps, but as I am new to both linux and windows I am unable to figure it out thus far. For clarity I have tried completely recreating the environment (I started with Kali, switched to Ubuntu) with the same result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu and Windows 10 version? Did you try to uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu distro?

Comment: Which pip version are you using? (Don't expect to find Python modules with `whereis`, that's not what the command is for.)

Comment: @Biswapriyo Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS & win 10.0. Yes I did

Comment: @grawity yes, I figured that might be the case given the lack of relevant feedback trying to. Pip version is 9.0.1 w/ python3

Comment: `module not found` typically means that the version of `pip` you used to install a module isn't associated with the version of Python you are using. You may want to try using `python -m pip install` rather than just `pip`. That said, it isn't uncommon for Linux to come with multiple versions of Python. So `pip3` may also be another option to consider.